# JavaFX Axis AutoRangeing ignore Series who are not visible

Tags: java, javafx, linechart, axis-labels

I got a `LineChart` with AutoRanging x and y axis, but I can hide some of my `Series` by toggling a button which changes the `.setVisible()` to it's opposite.

```
private LineChart<String, Number> chart;
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    chart.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
    chart.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);

}
```

Is there a way to still autorange the axis and let them ignore the invisible `Series`?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same issue recently and solved it by extending the LineChart - class the following way:

```
public class MyLineChart extends LineChart<String, Number> {

    public MyLineChart() {
        super(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAxisRange() {
        final Axis<String> xa = getXAxis();
        final Axis<Number> ya = getYAxis();
        List<String> xData = null;
        List<Number> yData = null;
        if (xa.isAutoRanging())
            xData = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (ya.isAutoRanging())
            yData = new ArrayList<Number>();
        if (xData != null || yData != null) {
            for (Series<String, Number> series : getData()) {
                if (series.getNode() != null && !series.getNode().isVisible())
                    continue;
                for (Data<String, Number> data : series.getData()) {
                    if (xData != null)
                        xData.add(data.getXValue());
                    if (yData != null)
                        yData.add(data.getYValue());
                }
            }
            // RT-32838 No need to invalidate range if there is one data item -
            // whose value is zero.
            if (xData != null && !(xData.size() == 1
                    && getXAxis().toNumericValue(xData.get(0)) == 0)) {
                xa.invalidateRange(xData);
            }
            if (yData != null && !(yData.size() == 1
                    && getYAxis().toNumericValue(yData.get(0)) == 0)) {
                ya.invalidateRange(yData);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, the method `updateAxisRange()` is responsible for the range bounds. The given code is taken from the original implentation, but with the following addition:

```
if (series.getNode() != null && !series.getNode().isVisible())
    continue;
```

With these changes, the invisible series gets skipped, and ignored by the autoRange-function.
To hide a series use the command: `getNode().setVisible(false)` on a Series-object. To embed the chart using FXML you need to remove the `<xAxis>` and `<yAxis>` in the FXML file. Additionally you need to change the LineChart to MyLineChart and update the imports.

This method can get adapted to other axis-types as well - just change them in the MyLineChart-class.

Hope I could help!